# What's the best place to learn Quantum Homology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, symplectic-geometry

I am a PhD student and I am trying to learn quantum homology. I already know some of the analysis, but I am struggling to really find a good readable reference which covers enough of the analysis to make it useful, but does not go into all details. So fx a good set of lecture notes. Of course there is McDuff and Salamon's opus, but I am aiming for something more accessible than that. 
Any ideas and input are much appreciated, thanks. :)

Mads

Comment: You probably learned it by now, but maybe it should be asked on Math Overflow.